# How I could redirect all my traffic to the TOR network?

Tags: macos, redirection, tor, traffic

I need to redirect all my traffic to the TOR network.

I have just installed Vidalia, but I think that I have not correctly configured my Tor-client. I have a Java desktop client that has to access a website. This allows us to connect 50 times then it reject our connection.

I would like to use Tor to create more conecctions. How I can configure my tor-client correctly? Is there any online how-to? Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you download the whole bundle? Basically, their bundle includes a proxy program. This will allow you to set your TCP/IP settings to use a proxy (one configured by your locally installed bundle). With this proxy enabled. All traffic from that computer will flow through the proxy (locally installed and hosted) and therefore be sent through the Tor network.

Remove proxy settings and you're off the Tor network.

Answer (score 1):

[Check out Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/).  It's what I used to use when I really wanted to wanted to beat that network traffic into submission.

Apple's "Proxy" settings *(at least not then)* didn't capture a LOT of whatever traffic I was trying to corral at the time..  (I don't really remember why I was so into this program, but I actually bought it, back in the day, so you can bet there wasn't a better alternative at the time...)

According to them...

> With Proxifier you can work with any Internet client (browsers, FTP, IRC, BitTorrent, messengers, telnet, SSH, video/audio, games...) through a network that is separated from Internet by a firewall (only one open port is required for a proxy tunnel to bypass firewall).

Aka, not just Safari, etc...

Also worth checking out...  [Charles Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).  It's a great tool for all sorts of stuff.... Not just hiding from the government on Tor, lol.. ;-)